# Maximum value of HashMap prints as NaN

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to print the maximum value of a HashMap.

It is a static variable which is defined as following in Results.java

```
public static HashMap<Double,Double> true_false=new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

I'm accessing it in another class and when I prints the HashMap it prints fine.

```
public double print_maxThreshold(){

  double maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(Results.true_false.values()));

}
```

When the Results.true_false prints the result gives as follows.

{0.01=0.5714285714285714, 0.05=0.5714285714285714, 0.1=0.6190476190476191, 0.15000000000000002=0.5405405405405405, 0.2=0.5625, 0.25=0.5714285714285715, 0.3=0.34782608695652173, 0.35=0.3157894736842105, 0.39999999999999997=0.2222222222222222, 0.44999999999999996=0.11764705882352941, 0.49999999999999994=0.11764705882352941, 0.5499999999999999=NaN, 0.6=NaN, 0.65=NaN, 0.7000000000000001=NaN, 0.7500000000000001=NaN, 0.8000000000000002=NaN, 0.8500000000000002=NaN, 0.9000000000000002=NaN, 0.9500000000000003=NaN}

But why not the maximum value prints as, 0.6190476190476191

please someone kindly explain

Comment: `NaN` messes up the comparator (all other values return `false` for the test "greater than NaN" -- they also return `false` for "lesser than" but that does not help you). You need to filter out the `NaN` first.

Comment: Thanks Thilo. It works

Comment: @Thilo `NaN` doesn't mess up the *comparator*. The comparator is actually very well-defined for handling of `NaN`, by ordering it above all other double values. You are right that it messes up *comparison operators*, but the comparator is not consistent with comparison operators. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553960/5221149).

Answer (score 3):

Javadoc of [`Collections.max(Collection<? extends T> coll)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) says:

> Returns the maximum element of the given collection, **according to the *natural ordering* of its elements**. All elements in the collection must implement the `Comparable` interface. Furthermore, all elements in the collection must be *mutually comparable* (that is, `e1.compareTo(e2)` must not throw a `ClassCastException` for any elements `e1` and `e2` in the collection).

This means that the ordering is defined by the [`Double.compareTo(Double anotherDouble)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-) method, which has the following javadoc description:

> **`Double.NaN` is** considered by this method to be equal to itself and **greater than all other `double` values** (including `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`).

That means, if there are any `NaN` values in the collection, `max()` will return `NaN`.

---

**UPDATE**

To exclude `NaN` for being considered, use Java 8 stream:

```
double maxValueInMap = Results.true_false
                              .values()
                              .stream()
                              .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                              .filter(d -> ! Double.isNaN(d))
                              .max()
                              .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

The advantage of this over [your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553833/5221149), is that it doesn't modify the original `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison to NaN is [undefined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html):

> NaN is unordered, so the numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and  >= return false if either or both operands are NaN (§15.20.1). The equality operator == returns false if either operand is NaN, and the inequality operator != returns true if either operand is NaN (§15.21.1). In particular, x!=x is true if and only if x is NaN, and (x=y) will be false if x or y is NaN.

But as @Andreas [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553759/maximum-value-of-hashmap-prints-as-nan/39553960#39553960) the correct reason is that Double.compareTo() considers NaN greater than all other double values.

Comment: Wrong answer. `Collections.max()` does not use comparison operators.

Comment: Not directly but eventually it does come down to Double.compare(d1,d2), does it not? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Double.java#Double.compareTo%28java.lang.Double%29

Comment: It does not, it comes down to `d1.compareTo(d2)`, which is not consistent with comparison operator, as explained in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-): *There are **two ways** in which comparisons performed by this method **differ from** those performed by the Java language numerical **comparison operators** (<, <=, ==, >=, >)*

Comment: Did you get the chance to look at the source of Double.compareTo(d) that I pasted in that link? It looks to me that it does make the call to Double.compare(d1,d2)

Comment: Perhaps. The javadoc says it the other way around, and `max()` explicitly says is calls `compareTo()`. Doesn't really matter, since `compare()` and `compareTo()` does the same thing, as the javadoc says, and neither are consistent with comparison operators when it comes to `NaN` values. In any case, your answer is a quote that does not answer the question, since the quote is not applicable to `NaN` handling when calling `max()`.

Comment: Yes, max() documents the call to compareTo() correct, because it is operating on the generic Comparable interface. Double is the implementing class in this case and it eventually does use comparison operator.  if (d1 < d2)   return -1;

Comment: But, as your own quote says, comparison operators treat `NaN` as *unordered*, while `compareTo()` treats `NaN` as *greater* than all other double values, i.e. *ordered*. Quoting what comparison operators do for `NaN` values is meaningless (aka not useful), when the actual method used is doing it differently, i.e. **not** doing what comparison operators so.

Comment: The unordered quote applies in general to comparison operators involving NaN. And the compareTo() documentation says that NaN is greater than all other numbers. I'm with you that far. But the reason that is the case is still the fact that compare(d1,d2) does a comparison d1 < d2  (which returns false) and hence the method that is going to return -1. Therefore, all numbers compared to NaN are going to be considered smaller than NaN

Comment: But your own quote says that `d1 < d2` is **false** if either is `NaN`, so it **will not** return -1. The source code *you* linked to even has a comment saying `// Neither val is NaN`. The actual handling of `NaN` is done by the obscure comparison of "long bits" below. So let me spell it out for you: comparison of `NaN` values, as implemented by `compareTo()`, does **not** rely on `double` *comparison operators*.

Comment: Ok I'm convinced. Thanks for spelling it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends thanks for suggestions.

With your suggestions it could be solved like this.

```
public double print_maxThreshold(){

  Results.true_false.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(NaN));

  double maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(Results.true_false.values()));
```

}

Now the maximum value prints fine.